# How to create trigger that will run a subquery to count data

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, constraints

I have a appointment table with patient_id. Now I want, a patient can make maximum 3 appointment. So I want to trigger that will check total appointment made by a patient using patient_id before insert data. The trigger will raise error if count > 3.

Can anyone tell me how can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: This is a pain because obvious methods result in a "mutating table" error.

Comment: You can't use trigger because you cannot pass parameter to triggers. And in your case, you need to check for particular patientid count and you cannot check count for that patientid in trigger since you cannot pass patientid as parameter. I would suggest you yo go for stored procs.

Comment: Actually, you can't use a trigger OR a stored proc (on their own) for this type of constraint, because your database session can't see rows inserted/updated by other sessions until after they commit. There are two methods you can use: (1) aggregate materialized view with a check constraint; or (2) serialize access to a patient_id with a database lock.